# How to map values on to a range in seaborn swarmplot?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, hue, colormap, swarmplot

I have an array of 100 float values in the range [0, 1]. (min and max values are not necessarily 0 and 1)

I want to map them to a hue in the "icefire" color palette, in a swarmplot. In other words I want the data points, the dots, to have a hue based on the 100-val-array.

Now, I do not want the lowest value to map to the "lowest" color in the palette; I want the lowest value to map to the "corresponding" color in the palette.

Let's imagine the color palette just goes from [0, 1] as well, so in the case of "icefire", 0 is light blue and 1 is light red (icefire goes from light blue, to black in the middle, to light red).

With that in mind, if the minimum value in the 100-val-array is 0.27, then I want that value to map to the color 0.27, i.e., in the case of icefire, somewhere in the blues.

I hope I am making myself clear.

I have no idea how the "palette" parameter in swarmplot works, but it is not doing what I want.

The reason I need this is because the color of the data point is important, as it reflects the actual value in the 100-val-array.

I believe by just using swarmplot(..., palette="icefire"), that is not what happens.

Comment: Did you try the `vmin` and `vmax` parameters that seaborn would carry over to `matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter`? I believe setting `vmin=0` and `vmax=1` does what you want: `swarmplot(..., palette="icefire", vmin=0, vmax=1)`

Comment: @EmilioSilva I did try that, yes. Like JohanC says in his answer, it doesn't do anything currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike a scatter plot, Seaborn's `swarmplot` (currently?) doesn't use a `vmin=` and `vmax=` parameter. The `swarmplot` considers the hue mapping as categorical. You can simulate working with a colormap by creating a `palette` as a dictionary that maps every possible `hue` value to its corresponding color.

Here is how your example could look like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['swarm 1'] * 100,
                   'y': np.random.normal(size=100),
                   'hue': np.random.uniform(0.27, 0.9, 100)})
cmap = sns.color_palette('icefire', as_cmap=True)
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)  # 0 and 1 are the defaults, but you can adapt these to fit other uses
palette = {h: cmap(norm(h)) for h in df['hue']}

ax = sns.swarmplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', hue='hue', palette=palette)
ax.legend_.remove()  # remove the categorical legend
plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm), ax=ax)  # optionally add a colorbar
plt.show()
```

[image: swarmplot with colormapped hue]

Comment: He went and did it!! :'D Thank you, this solved it. What is funny, I actually had this exact thought when I went out for a walk, I didn't implement it though;
Thank you!